# Cannot connect to Port 5432

Tags: postgresql

My company has a **Linux Database** server. I only have one user that needs access to this server.

He is using **PostgreSQL** to access this server. It has been working fine for over a year. Today when he tried to log on he got this message

```
SERVER DOESN'T LISTEN
```

The server doesn't accept connections, the connection library reports:

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274d/10061) is the server running on host 192.168.xx.xx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

The server has been rebooted and I can ping the Correct IP.
If I remote with Putty I can run NETSTAT  and I DO NOT see port 5432 listening.

I have never used Linux before and could use some help.
I don't know why 5432 stopped listening, but I think I would be ok if I can make port 5432 listen.

Comment: In postgresql.conf did you set `listen_addresses` to `localhost, private_ip`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the **postgresql** service is not running (either it crashed or it is not configured to start at boot time, since you rebooted the server).

Depending on the version of Ubuntu you are using, you should try to start it with command

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

or with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

If the service starts without error, the application should be running fine.

Comment: Syldes, You are right the server was not running, But when I tried to start it, it failed. The error message was No space left on drive. I need to check the log output to see what is going on.I am not sure where to find the log. I think if I can clean some stuff off this drive I will be back in business.

Comment: @Jerry, yes it seems you need to recover/add free space on the drive. **df -h** command might help to find which mount point is full.

Comment: also @Jerry you can do `ncdu /` to check the disk and see what is taking up space. you might need to install `ncdu` with `apt install ncdu`